# Bluetooth ASCII protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, communication

I'm trying to communicate with a bluetooth device. The information I have on the device states that

"The communications protocol is ASCII, commas separate output values. The message is terminated by carriage return and line feed pair. When saved as a file using a terminal emulator these results can be read into an Excel spreadsheet."

How do I send and receive from this device? I have tried using InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter, but I don't think that's working.

EDIT:

for sending data I'm trying:

```
public void send(String s){
            try {
                writer.write(s);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

where

```
try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            inStream = tmpIn;
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(tmpOut);
```

You can also see there where I am using inStream that is a simple InputStream. I have also tried InputStreamReader, but I just got random characters back. With the InputStream I am only reading 4 bytes no matter what I send the device, so I'm not sure if even the sending is working.

What should I be using? Thanks!

Comment: More detail, please. What code have you tried, and what problems are you running into? Include any results or error messages.

Comment: I added more details to my question, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: Never use the encoding-less constructors or methods when there is one that allows you to specify the encoding. If you don't specify the encoding you'll get the platform default encoding, which is essentially an euphemism for "random encoding", leading to platform dependent code. If you really mean `ASCII` (which is only 7 bits) you should specify it: `new OutputStreamWriter(tmpOut, "ASCII")`, but i suspect it's actually `ISO-8859-1` or some other 8 bit encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am following up on this in case anyone else is having the same problems. One of the problems I was having was that the device I was trying to communicate with was expecting a specific order of /n and /r and would lock up if that was incorrect so I had no was of knowing if it was working or not.

Here is he code I use for sending and receiving, I have used it on a couple of devices now and it seems to work well.

```
    /**
 * This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
 * It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
 */
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket socket;
    private final InputStream inStream;
    private final OutputStream outStream;
    private final DataInputStream datIn;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create ConnectedThread");
        this.socket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "temp sockets not created", e);
        }

        inStream = tmpIn;
        outStream = tmpOut;
        datIn = new DataInputStream(inStream);
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN ConnectedThread");
        Bundle data = new Bundle();

        // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
        while (true) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Reading...");
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                String results;
                Log.i(TAG, "Recieved:");
                results = datIn.readLine();
                Log.i(TAG, results);

             // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                data.putString("results", results);
                Message m = handler.obtainMessage(); // get a new message from the handler
                m.setData(data); // add the data to the message
                m.what = MESSAGE_READ;
                handler.sendMessage(m);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                handler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_DISCONNECTED).sendToTarget();
                setState(STATE_NONE);
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write to the connected OutStream.
     * @param buffer  The bytes to write
     */
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            outStream.write(buffer);
            Log.i(TAG, "Sending: " + new String(buffer));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "close() of connect socket failed", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Write to the ConnectedThread in an unsynchronized manner
 * @param out The bytes to write
 * @see ConnectedThread#write(byte[])
 */
public void send(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (state != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = connectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Java documentation on IO Streams to make the whole picture.

For retrieval I assume you are using [`InputStream.read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) method, which reads one byte at a time. To retrieve several bytes at a time you should use `byte[]` buffer. But that's not your case, just FYI.

In your case you don't need to use `InputStream` methods, but `InputStreamReader` instead, because 
`Reader` operates on characters, not bytes. As stated in your quotation of protocol description, you have separate lines of ASCII. In this situation [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is handy, because it has `readLine()` method.

So you can just

```
    in = socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

And then

```
    String line = br.readLine();
```

For sending data you should use OutputStreamWriter.

**REMEMBER:Please close streams after use!!! in `finaly{}` clause**